# Django url dispatcher uses strings to specify function, why?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

The Django documentation shows examples like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),

]
```

However, I have seen some code that looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'myapp.views.special_case_2003'),

]
```

Where `special_case_2003` is the name of a function in `myapp/views.py`. 
What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'myapp.views.special_case_2003'),
]
```

Code like this is out of date. Providing the view as a string like this [is deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#passing-a-string-as-view-to-url), and [does not work in Django 1.10+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10). In Django 1.10+, you must use the callable.

Comment: It is still ok to use strings in `include` though